# How to check for `null` from Newtonsoft when the compiler insists that it isn't possible?

Tags: .net, f#, null, json.net, option-type

Our project is mixed C# & F# with the ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET core defaults to Newtonsoft for serializing/deserializing everywhere, and the swagger documentation generation (nswag) also relies on CLI(Mutable)-like DTOs to generate correct types.

Our DTOs are defined in F# like so:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Query =
    { Status: string
      Offset: int
      Limit: int }
```

Which makes it trivial for Newtonsoft to serialize, and nswag to generate swagger doc.

But..! I'm having a extremely hard time with the null/option "mismatch". C#/Newtonsoft/NSwag insists on using `null`, and will not understand F#'s `option`. So in my F# I *have* to check for nulls and convert them to option; and also convert my options back to nulls when converting from domain back to DTO.

But F# insists that null isn't a possible to the point where I'm not even allowed to check: The compiler gives me: "The type {...} does not have 'null' as a proper value". But fact is that *runtime*, it *IS* null because that's how Newtonsoft works. Newtonsoft is *the* .NET standard it seems, so I don't think using something else is feasible unfortunately.

How can I check for nulls even though F# thinks it's impossible for it to be null?

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer right now, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/values/null-values has the answer you need. TL;DR: use the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute on your type.

Comment: Have you actually tried `option`? Last I checked, JSON.NET did support it.

Comment: I tried option, it makes the most horrible JSON imaginable (still). Are you sure it works for you (out of the box?)? @rmunn: I've tried to use [<AllowNullLiteral>] already, but it doesn't allow it: "Records, unions, abbreviation and struct types does cannot have the 'AllowNullLiteral' attribute"

Comment: Don’t have time for a complete answer either, but one often used utility for this is FSharpLU.json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple way to overcome this (in general) is to box the value before checking for null.

`let isReallyNull value = value |> box |> isNull`

Then you can check the object instances returned by Newtonsoft in your normal logic:

```
if dto |> isReallyNull
then None
else Some dto
```

Here's a complete example using `Unchecked.defaultof` to generate a null value for a type the compiler says can't be null:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyDto =
    {
        Status: string
        Offset: int
        Limit: int
    }

let isReallyNull value = value |> box |> isNull

let dto = Unchecked.defaultof<MyDto>

// if dto |> isNull (* Compiler complains that MyDto does not have null as a proper value *)
if dto |> isReallyNull
then printfn "The DTO is null"
else printfn "The DTO is non-null"
```

Comment: Thanks <3 This works. This was quite a headache. Microsoft's documentation was of little help, and googling didn't give me any results. I'm happy there's a solution. However, it's a little surprising just how much of an uphill struggle it is to get Newtonsoft/.NET-stuff to work with F# in general. It often feels like I'm the first & only person in the world to json serialize F# types. I'm coming from Scala where JSON serialization was abundant and very polished. Kinda sad to have to "hack" the F# compiler to force it to use nulls to have basic JSON support. =/

Comment: Note that deserializing into a class with AllowNullLiteral all works as you’d expect it. No need to tell the compiler that it doesn’t understand what’s going on :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let optionalValue = Option.ofObj dto
```

As Aaron suggests, if dto is a record type, then you would need to do this:

```
let optionalValue = dto |> box |> Option.ofObj
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this will work if the DTO type is an F# Record.  Without boxing it first, you will have the same problem as the OP.  If you try it in the example I posted above by adding the line `let maybeDto = dto |> Option.ofObj`, you'll get the compiler error saying `MyDto does not have null as a proper value`.